# How to work on two UIViewControllers one in swift and other in objective-c..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am rewriting my app which was in Objective-C to Swift.
I was wondering if I can use some old `UIViewControllers` from my previous app in my new application without having to rewrite these in Swift.
Is it possible?

Comment: You should be able to mix them. They are `UIViewController` after all, it's the CocoaTouch framework, it's not dependent of the language used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a bridging header.

When you import Objective-C files into a swift project (let's call the project MyApp), it should ask if you want to create the bridging header `MyApp-Bridging-Header.h`. If it doesn't ask, you can always create it yourself, but if you do it this way make sure you include it under the `Swift Compiler - Code Generator -> Objective-C Bridging Header` in the `Build Settings` of your project. Inside this file you can write the import for your Objective-C file e.g.:

```
#import "MyUIViewController.h"
```

This will import them to the project, so that they are compatible with the other Swift files.
Then in your swift class you can refer to that Objective-C view controller like you would any other swift class, e.g.:

```
let myUIViewController = MyUIViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Yes it will work

I also work with my previous project and i imported my old Objective-C code into the Swift project making **Bridge header** for accessing that Objective-C UIViewController from Swift class. You directly assign your Objective-C UiViewcontroller class in the StoryBoard UIviewController and no need to rewrite any coad again for UIViewController.if you want to access Objective-C class inside your Swift Controller Class you need to make first Bridge header file then do this.

[image]

```
 //In Swift Controller you can call your Objective-C Class 
 let myView = MyController() // This is Objective-C controller
 myView.updatemyProfile() // Can call function like Objective-C here
```